# How do i label a line in KML only on mouseover

Tags: mouseevent, line, kml, mouseover, google-earth

i am creating a KML File with VBA.
I the content of the file are points and the lines in between.

Now i want to only show name of the line on mouseover.
I found out that gx:labelVisibility 1 /gx:labelVisibility is showing the name of the line.
But i cant get the lable to only show on mouseover.

Thank you for the help!

Here is the code with some *trys*:

```
   <Style id="s_definition">
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>99ffffff</color>     
        <scale>2</scale>    
      </LabelStyle>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <width>6</width>
        <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>

    <Style id="s_definition_hl">
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>00ffffff</color>     
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ffeb07ff</color>
        <width>8</width>
        <gx:labelVisibility>0</gx:labelVisibility>      
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>

    <StyleMap id="m_definition">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#s_definition</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#s_definition_hl</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>

    <Placemark id="feat_2">
      <name>My Line</name>
      <styleUrl>#m_definition</styleUrl>
      <LineString id="geom_0">
        <coordinates>0,0,0.0 1,1,0.0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>

</Document>
```